# Transparent background in PNG, but MP4 background is black

Tags: rendering

I've managed to render PNGs which have my machine on a transparent background, but I want to have a video of it.  I've tried lots of settings to no avail....the film/transparent setting doesn't seem to do anything.

Every vid I've rendered, whether it be straight from Blender Render or Cycles Render or via creating a film strip from the PNGs via Video Editor and creating a vid from there, turns up with a black background from my scene.

Whats the trick?

Thanks!

Comment: As far as I know no video format supports alpha channels, render as an image sequence instead.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos there are versions of Prores that do support Alpha channels: ProRes4444 and the high bitrate versions of the DNxHD and DNxHR codecs. But you can't encode directly on them from blender. You would need an external encoder or ffmpeg

Answer (score 2):

Mp4 does not support alpha channel. You need to encode using a codec that does.